# M8[D] for datetime

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

What is `M8[D]` type in the following? Is there some references for full type we can set?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
d = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['2015-07-01']})
print(d.astype('M8[D]'))
print(np.datetime64('1979-03-22').dtype)
```

Answer (score 2):

`'M8[D]'` is a 8 bype datetime type (`M`) ([docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html#specifying-and-constructing-data-types)) with day (`D`) units. See [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html#datetime-units) for all available datetime units and further examples.